# Как в в html c помощью JavaScript присвоить переменной введенный текст?

Tags: javascript, html

Вычитал что это делается через свойство value. Но я не разобрался что и куда прописать?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Тег</title>
 </head>
 <body>

  <form action="textarea1.php" method="post"></form>
    <p ><b>Введите ваш отзыв:</b></p>
    <p><textarea rows="10" cols="45" name="text"value="myFunction().A"  ></textarea></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Отправить"></p>
  </form>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: за желание разобраться Вам плюс, но постарайтесь, пожалуйста, чуть подробнее описывать желаемый результат. )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

если хотите получить текст при нажатии на кнопку:

(для получения текста при его вводе надо уже на textarea отслеживать другие события)

```js
function analyze() {
    let textarea = document.querySelector('.mytext');
    console.log(textarea.value);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Тег</title>
 </head>
 <body>

  <form action="textarea1.php" method="post"></form>
    <p><b>Введите ваш отзыв:</b></p>
    <p><textarea class = 'mytext' rows="10" cols="45" name="text">Какой-то текст</textarea></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Отправить" onClick='analyze()'></p>
  </form>

 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        let text = document.getElementsByName('text')[0];
        text.addEventListener('input', function (t) {
            let p = document.getElementById('val');
            p.innerText = this.value;

        });
    })
```

```html
<form action="textarea1.php" method="post"></form>
<p><b>Введите ваш отзыв:</b><br><b id="val"></b></p>
<p><textarea rows="10" cols="45" name="text"></textarea></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Отправить"></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const form = document.querySelector('.form');
const textarea = form.querySelector('.textarea');

form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const value = textarea.value;
  console.log(value);
});
```

```html
<form action="textarea1.php" class="form" method="post">
  <p><b>Введите ваш отзыв:</b></p>
  <p><textarea rows="5" cols="20" name="text" class="textarea"></textarea></p>
  <p><input type="submit" value="Отправить"></p>
</form>
```